# Prove that $x=0.1234567891011\cdots$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove that $x=0.1234567891011\cdots$ is irrational

Proof: We argue by contradiction. Suppose $x$ is rational, then its decimal expansion ultimately periodic. Let $p$ denote the period of this expansion. Now consider a block $B=000 \cdots0$ $  p$ times since any integer of the form $10^k$ with $ k \geq p$ contains $p$ consecutive $0$'s . this block must accure infinitely often in the decimal expansion of $x$ by our assumption that this expansion is ultimately periodic with period $p$ , this implies that $B$ must be the repeating period block. Which means that the sequence consists of all $0$'s from some point onwards. but this clearly contradicts the construction of the sequence.

This proof is correct? If it is not, what's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the period is $P=1234567891011$, then somewhere in the decimals you are sure to find $P$ followed by $P+1$, i.e. $1234567891011123456789101\color{red}2$, by the definition of the Champernowne constant. This contradicts periodicity.

Answer (score 3):

The statement "this implies $B$ must be the repeating block" bothers me a bit.

Surely $C = 111 \cdots 1$ $p$ times also occurs infinitely often, as does every other string of length $p$.